# Magento 1 - Sales_Order_Place_Before event not working

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, log

I am new to magento. I am using `Sales_order_place_before` event in my module. I have seen lots of valuable posts/discussions regarding this issue. But I haven't found a solution yet. So I hope someone will help me on this issue.

#### config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Observersample_Event>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Observersample_Event>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <Observersample_Event>
                <class>Observersample_Event_Model</class>
            </Observersample_Event>
        </models>
        <events>
            <slaes_order_place_before>
                <observers>
                    <observersample_event_model_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Observersample_Event_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>example</method>
                    </observersample_event_model_observer>
                </observers>
            </slaes_order_place_before>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

#### observer.php:

```
class Observersample_Event_Model_Observer{

    public function example($observer){

        Mage::log("Order is placed");
    }
}
```

And I have also enabled the log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event name is wrong. It should be `slaes_order_place_before` to `sales_order_place_before`. There is no such event with name  `slaes_order_place_before`

Comment: Ah!! now i am getting the log message..Thanks @Amit Bera

Comment: k. ............................

Answer (score 4):

your observer name has the typo mistake it should be `sales_order_place_before`

Comment: Ah!! now i am getting the log message..Thanks @Pradeep Sanku