# Blacklist customers from placing orders

Tags: magento-1.7, orders, customer-attribute

I have made a custom attribute `blacklisted` in the customer grid. I have created the attribute directly from `phpmyadmin`.

I will blacklist customers manually.

Now, while placing an order, if, for the customer, blacklisted='Yes', he should not be able to place order. I want to check this attribute using the customer's email id.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like this question but I would use a different approach.

Firstly I would create a customer group called `blacklisted` then use the following code to display or hide content as needed.

```
$groupId = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId();
$group = Mage::getModel('customer/group')->load($groupId);  
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() && $group->getCode()=="blacklisted"):
//Content
endif;
```

Comment: Using this approach, how can I bar him from placing any further orders ?

Comment: You could wrap it around the place order button or even the whole checkout so the page looks totally different to blacklisted customers and then display a warning message.

Comment: okay. Thank you for the help. Your idea of creating a group is superb :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an observer method and call it on the event  `sales_order_place_before`.

In this method you can get the customer id from session and load that customer. Now you will get all the attribute value of customer.

If its blacklisted then return false.

You can follow this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/70820/sales-order-place-before-event-not-working) to create observer on event.